# How to program sound card to output a specific signal?

Tags: audio, hardware, multimedia

I'm trying to program my sound card to output specific values.

Let's say, I have below sequence

```
[1,2,3,2,10,4,1,50,20,1]
```

I want the sound card to output the specified analog signal according to this sequence.

I can use Windows Multimedia API of course. However, my task is light-weighted and I don't want to use such heavy framework.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you generate a .wav file and play it with a media player.

It's easy with python and its `wave` module. In my below example I worked with python 3.3

```
import wave
import struct

# define your sequence
frames = [1,2,3,2,10,4,1,50,20,1]

output = wave.open('out.wav', mode='wb') # create the file that will contain your sequence
output.setnchannels(1) # 1 for mono
output.setsampwidth(1) # resolution in number of bytes
output.setframerate(10) # sampling rate, being usually 44100 Hz
output.setnframes(len(frames)) # sequence length

for i in range(0, len(frames)):
    output.writeframes(struct.pack('h',frames[i])) # convert to string in hex format

# close the file, you're done
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line if you use Matlab or the free equivalent, Octave. The relevant documentation is [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/audio/function/soundsc.html).

> ```
> soundsc(x, fs, [ lo, hi ])
>     Scale the signal so that [lo, hi] -> [-1, 1], then play it
>     at sampling rate fs.  If fs is empty, then the default 8000 Hz
>     sampling rate is used.
> ```

Your function call in the console would look like this ...

```
soundsc([1,2,3,2,10,4,1,50,20,1], fs, [1 50]);
```

... or like this with manual normalisation of the positive integer vector to give values between +/- 1 ...

```
x = [1,2,3,2,10,4,1,50,20,1];
x=x-min(x); % get values to range from zero up
x=x/max(x); % get floating point values to range between 0.0 and 1.0
x=x*2-1;    % get values to range between +/- 1.0;
soundsc(x);
```